# How long is too long for sous vide steak

Tags: steak, sous-vide

I have *sous vide* for a while with mixed success. Mostly good, but still mixed.  One thing I question which I hoping to get opinion on is time to sous vide beef (steak specifically, e.g. ribeye or strip).

I have read and heard where people have left beef in the bath for 24+ hours and rave about it. All the Anovo guidelines say 4 hours or less. I have not tried more than four hours.  What gives, and what is overdoing it with sous vide cooking?

Answer (score 8):

When cooking low temperature, over time the texture of the protein that you are cooking changes.  For a tough cut, like a shank, or short rib, this is desirable, and where you would see cooking times of 12, 24, 48 hours...or longer.  Most people want to enjoy a steak that chews like the traditionally cooked product.  After 3 to 4 hours, the texture of your steak will change.  It will become more mushy.  That is why it is recommended that you only cook until done (1 to 2 hours).  So, overdoing it, as you describe it, would be cooking it too long so that the texture becomes undesirable. For a steak, I think 4 hours would be pushing it.

Answer (score 5):

**TLDR**: Just like pork, steak cooked for an extended period of time starts to shred and get mushy. It's not what most would call a traditional steak, but if you're open minded, people like pulled pork as well as pork chops...

**Pictures**:

Serious Eats has very thorough sous vide guides on both [steak](https://www.seriouseats.com/2015/06/food-lab-complete-guide-to-sous-vide-steak.html) and [chicken](https://www.seriouseats.com/2015/07/the-food-lab-complete-guide-to-sous-vide-chicken-breast.html).

Here's what they have on [steak timing](https://www.seriouseats.com/2015/06/food-lab-complete-guide-to-sous-vide-steak.html#time):

> To figure out exactly what happens when you cook steak sous vide for
>   extended periods, I cooked identical steaks at 130°F (54°C) for
>   periods ranging from one hour all the way up to 48 hours. I found that
>   the most important differences typically occurred between the four-
>   and 24-hour marks.
>
> Take a look at these slices of steak I've cut off and torn:
>
> [image]
>   As you can see, the steak cooked for just one hour stretches and pulls
>   when you tear it. This gives the steak a pleasant amount of chew. It's
>   still tender, but it tastes like a steak. By the time we hit four
>   hours, that chew has been reduced a bit. Connective tissue has broken
>   down, and individual muscle fibrils split apart easily instead of
>   sticking together, though a four-hour steak is still pretty decent.
>
> Head all the way over to the 24-hour mark or beyond, and your steak
>   ends up nearly shredding as you pull it apart. It's a strange
>   mouthfeel: The steak is still plenty juicy (a steak cooked 24 hours
>   loses barely any more moisture than a steak cooked for one hour), but
>   the meat shreds instead of offering resistance or chew.